# PHP mysqli best practice error handling

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and mysqli, and I've managed to connect to my MySQL database using this PHP code:

```
<?php
function connect(){
    define('DB_USER', 'my_user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_pw');
    define('DB_HOST', 'my_host');
    define('DB_NAME', 'my_name');

    global $db_conn;
    $db_conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

}

function disconnect(){
    mysqli_close($db_conn);

}

addUser($username, $password, $role){
    openConnection();
    global $db_conn;
    //Formulate the query
    $q = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username', '$password' , '$role')";
    //query database
    mysqli_query($db_conn, $q);
    closeConnection();
}
```

I'm wondering about error handling: Is there a best practice for database error handling in PHP? 
I'm thinking something like:

```
addUser($username, $password, $role){
    openConnection();
    global $db_conn;
    //Formulate the query
    $q = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username', '$password' , '$role')";
    //query database, return feedback to the caller
    $feedback = mysqli_query($db_conn, $q);
    closeConnection();
    return $feedback;
}

$feedback = addUser('name','pw','role'); 
if($feedback == "Error"){
//Display error to user
}
```

And there should be something similar to handle if the DB connection fails. Could anyone help me out with finding the best practice for database related error handling in PHP?

EDIT: After reading comments, I've removed all '@'characters from my code, since they suppress the warnings that PHP produces.

Comment: Everytime you add an @ sign in front of a line of code, you will force php to not give errors about that line of code

Comment: `@mysqli_connect` that `@` is certainly not one of the *best practices*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the @ operator, you're suppressing the query error (see http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). As mentioned in the comments, you should really checkout an object oriented way of doing database operations (you may want to take a look at http://php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php -with pdo you can use exception handling with PDOException).

Regarding your specific code you can use the following error handling:

```
<?php
function connect(){
    define('DB_USER', 'my_user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_pw');
    define('DB_HOST', 'my_host');
    define('DB_NAME', 'my_name');

    global $db_conn;
    $db_conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error())

}

function disconnect(){
    mysqli_close($db_conn);

}

addUser($username, $password, $role){
    openConnection();
    global $db_conn;
    //Formulate the query
    $q = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username', '$password' , '$role')";
    //query database
    if (mysqli_query($db_conn, $q) === false)
    {
       throw new Exception(mysqli_error($db_conn));
    }
    closeConnection();

    return true;
}
```

and then use it like this

```
try {
  if (addUser('name','pw','role'))
  {
     echo "all went well";
  }
} catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo "Mysql error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!
So if I understand this code correctly; 
If mysqli_query($db_conn, $q) returns false (= something went wrong with the database) we throw an exception to the "client", which displays the error message?

Comment: Also, what about handling errors produced by 'mysqli_connect(...)'?

Comment: mysqli_connect also returns false on errors, so you could do something similar here: if (!@mysqli_connect()) { throw new Exception('Error while connecting: ' . mysqli_error()); }

Comment: It seems like ´or die(mysqli_error()´ printed it well enough :) thanks for you input